Writing a data frame to a worksheet after creating the worksheet with add_worksheet()
I am using ExcelWriter to create a workbook where there will be multiple data frames written to each sheet. In addition, I want to add certain other information to other cells in the sheet.
How do I write a dataframe to my worksheet, using to_excel() or similar, after having created the worksheet using add_worksheet()?
When I tried the following code, I received the exception: DuplicateWorksheetName: Sheetname 'Data', with case ignored, is already in use.
# Create some Pandas dataframes from some data.
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Data": [11, 12, 13, 14]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Data": [21, 22, 23, 24]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({"Data": [31, 32, 33, 34]})

with pd.ExcelWriter("pandas_multiple.xlsx") as writer:
    
    workbook  = writer.book
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("Data") # Without these two lines, everything works,
    worksheet.write(0, 0, 'Hello')             # but without the text.
    
    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Data",startrow = 3)
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Data",startrow = 9)
    df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Data",startrow = 15)
    
writer.close()


Have a look at this answer. Perhaps you haven't yet installed xlsxwriter?

@ouroboros1 xlsxwriter is definitely installed, as I can use it in other places in my real application.

Maybe explicitly setting the engine pd.ExcelWriter("pandas_multiple.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter"). Unable to reproduce the issue here: working just fine. Except that you don't need writer.close().

@ouroboros1 Hmmm.... even with the explicit call, it gives me the error.

Does this answer your question? Xlsxwriter in pandas and outside of pandas lockout

@OCa It doesn't answer the question, but it is a similar problem. The solution proposed, changing the order of operations, is precisely what I am trying to avoid.

can you run following code to check versions installed ?
print("Pandas version:", pd.__version__) and
print("XlsxWriter version:", xlsxwriter.__version__)
Your code works just fine for me with following config : Python version : 3.12.3, Pandas version: 2.2.1, XlsxWriter version: 3.1.1

@antoine Pandas version: 1.3.5 and XlsxWriter version: 1.2.7
If it's a versioning issue I might just be stuck, since this isn't an environment I have control over.

if @ouroboros1 has more recent versions too, it's starting to look like this might be the issue
